# how to send request infinitely in react without rendering the whole component for live feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am receiving infinite images from back end (Django Rest) via live feed, everytime live feed gives separate unique image and I want to show in react in a div of a component,Everytime one image came in response and I want to show it in a div of a component, first I have tried an infinite function which send requests infinitely to api and get single image everytime in response but in this way the whole page reloads I want  only div to reload in which images came from backend and changes without reloading whole page, what can be the best approach for this?

```
runInfinite=()=>{

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/process_image/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({baseimage: res.data})
            });
    };

render(){
          if (this.state.flag){           // flag will always be true for infinite run
            this.runInfinite()
        }
return(   
         <div>
           {this.state.baseimage?<img  src={"data:image/png;base64," +  this.state.baseimage}/>:<h1>Hello</h1>}  // get image(single) from request's response
         </div>
)
}
```

How can I get image from request without reloading the whole component and can there be other better approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is you should use Sockets. But if it is not required for you, you can call runInfinite() method using specific interval :

```
render(){
   if (this.state.flag){
        setInterval(()=> { this.runInfinite(); }, 1000);
   }
}
```

Specify the time which is suitable to you.

Comment: Yeh Its working but after some time it becomes slow or stop I want to change the images in fast speed,in start the images changes rapidky but after sometime it become slow or stop i have use cursor then again it starts changing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of infinite requests, a better approach would be to use sockets.

A suggested tutorial: https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34

In your case since it's specific to Django. Checkout Django Channels too.